# robocopy: only list what will be deleted from destination

Tags: sync, robocopy

I want to list what will be deleted from the destination directory. I tried:

```
robocopy U:\ R:\ /L /E /NOCOPY /PURGE
```

Comment: Also, why the PowerShell tag? Are you trying to call this from PowerShell?

Comment: I was trying both cmd and powershell.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following params should output just the list of affected files:

```
/l /njh /njs /nc /ns /ndl
```

Comment: This provides a blank list even though I intentionally created extra files on the destination.